# Splitting the page into four blocks

Tags: minipage

I would like to split a top and bottom marginless page into **four sectors** and fill each of these sectors with vertically centered text.  Since total height of the page is 29.7cm, one sector should be 7.425cm.  I came upon this solution:

```
\documentclass[12pt,parskip=half]{scrbook}
\usepackage[vmargin={0cm,0cm},hmargin={3cm,3cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

% this should go on the first page
\begin{minipage}[c][7.425cm][c]{15cm}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[c][7.425cm][c]{15cm}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[c][7.425cm][c]{15cm}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[c][7.425cm][t]{15cm}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}

% this should go on the second page
\begin{minipage}[c][7.425cm][c]{15cm}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[c][7.425cm][c]{15cm}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

However it does not work.  It throws the fourth minipage on the new page and spread the the tree remaining over the whole page.  Is there any way to do that properly?

Comment: The height of mini pages had to be smaller than 1/4  paper height. Between mini pages is empty vertical space determined with `\parskip`. Try with `\parskip=0pt` in begin of this page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several spacing issues:

- `vmargin=0pt`, that means, the bottom is the end of the paper and `\maxdepth` must be set to zero. `\maxdepth` allows the baseline on the bottom and descenders would stick outside of the paper.
- `\noindent` removes the paragraph indent, if `\parindent` is not zero.
- `\vspace{-\parskip}` neutralizes the space between paragraphs.
- `\nointerlineskip` removes the interline skip between boxes (default is 1pt, enough to push the fourth box to the second page.)

Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, parskip=half]{scrbook}
\usepackage[vmargin=0cm, hmargin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\maxdepth}{0pt}% Do not go below the bottom margin,
%  because it would be outside of the paper

\pagestyle{empty}% page number would be off page

\begin{document}
\begingroup
  \newcommand*{\nospace}{%
    \par
    \nointerlineskip
    \vspace{-\parskip}%
    % \hrule\vspace{-.4pt}% for debugging
    \noindent
  }

  % this should go on the first page
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}[c][.25\textheight][c]{\textwidth}
  \lipsum[1]
  \end{minipage}

  \nospace
  \begin{minipage}[c][.25\textheight][c]{\textwidth}
  \lipsum[1]
  \end{minipage}

  \nospace
  \begin{minipage}[c][.25\textheight][c]{\textwidth}
  \lipsum[1]
  \end{minipage}

  \nospace
  \begin{minipage}[c][.25\textheight][c]{\textwidth}
  \lipsum[1]
  \end{minipage}

  % this should go on the second page
  \nospace
  \begin{minipage}[c][.25\textheight][c]{\textwidth}
  \lipsum[1]
  \end{minipage}

  \nospace
  \begin{minipage}[c][.25\textheight][c]{\textwidth}
  \lipsum[1]
  \end{minipage}

  \par
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

First page:

> [image: Page 1]